# Postgres regular expression for a number of elements

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to write a Postgres regular expression to find records where a column has numbers only and a string length of more than 5.

E.g.: column `hello` has `'0 1 1 2 1'` or `'12345'`.

Or to keep it simple I want a regular express that will identify rows that has 5 or more numbers in it.

How do I write that regex?

Comment: You column always contains only numbers , and perhaps spaces ?

Comment: And by "numbers" you mean "digits", right? And you want rows where the column has only digits and space characters, also right?

Comment: Also: `length of more than 5` or `5 or more numbers`, which will it be? Assuming "5 or more" ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
   VALUES 
    ('98765')
   ,('1 2 3 4 5')
   ,('143562465')
   ,(' 1 2 5  3 235')
   ,(' 1 2 5  3 235s')
   ,('y 1 2 5  3 235')
   ,('245no')
   ,('1234')
    ) sub(hello)
WHERE  hello ~ '^[\d ]+$'
AND    length(translate(hello, ' ','')) > 4
```

Result:

```
98765
1 2 3 4 5
143562465
 1 2 5  3 235
```

Explain [regular expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

`\d` .. regexp shorthand for [digit] character class
`[\d ]` .. digits or space
`^` .. start of sting
`$` .. end of string

And [`translate()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is the fastest method to replace single characters, just space in this example.

Of if you are looking for a **single regular expression** (probably slower than the above):

```
WHERE hello ~ '^ *(\d *){5,}$'
```

Explain:
`*` .. zero or more spaces
`(\d *)` .. an atom consisting of a digit followed by zero or more space chars
`{5,}` .. the previous atom 5 or more times