# Function taking forever to run for large number of records

Tags: postgresql, function, concurrency, sql-update, plpgsql

I have created the following function in Postgres 9.3.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_result(val1 text, val2 text)
RETURNS text AS 
$BODY
$Declare

result text;

BEGIN

select min(id) into result from table 
where id_used is null and id_type = val2;

update table set 
id_used = 'Y', 
col1 = val1,  
id_used_date = now() 
where id_type = val2 
and id = result;

RETURN result;

END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

When I run this function in a loop of over a 1000 or more records it just does freezing and just says "query is running". When I check my table nothing is being updated. When I run it for one or two records it runs fine.

Example of the function when being run:

```
select get_result('123','idtype');
```

table columns:

```
id character varying(200),
col1 character varying(200),
id_used character varying(1),
id_used_date timestamp without time zone,
id_type character(200)
```

`id` is the table index.

Can someone help?

Comment: run your select with explain keyword and you will see it does table scan. So apply proper index and use GROUP BY clause when using aggregate functions wherever possible.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Your table cannot be called `table`. And the line break in `$BODY $` cannot be either. Rather post your actual function. What you posted may be hiding problems. Also crucial: *How* do you loop exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are running into **race conditions**. When you run your function a 1000 times in quick succession in *separate transactions*, something like this happens:

```sql
T1            T2            T3            ...
SELECT max(id) -- id 1
              SELECT max(id)  -- id 1
                            SELECT max(id)  -- id 1
                                          ...
              Row id 1 locked, wait ...
                            Row id 1 locked, wait ...
UPDATE id 1
                                          ... 

COMMIT
              Wake up, UPDATE id 1 again!
              COMMIT
                            Wake up, UPDATE id 1 again!
                            COMMIT
                                          ...
```

Largely rewritten and simplified as SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_result(val1 text, val2 text)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql AS 
$func$
UPDATE tbl t
SET    id_used      = 'Y'
     , col1         = val1
     , id_used_date = now() 
FROM  (
   SELECT id
   FROM   tbl 
   WHERE  id_used IS NULL
   AND    id_type = val2
   ORDER  BY id
   LIMIT  1
   FOR    UPDATE   -- lock to avoid race condition! see below ...
   ) t1
WHERE  t.id_type = val2
-- AND t.id_used IS NULL  -- repeat condition (not if row is locked)
AND    t.id = t1.id
RETURNING  id;
$func$;
```

Related question with a lot more explanation:

- [Atomic UPDATE .. SELECT in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532550/atomic-update-select-in-postgres/11568880#11568880)

#### Explanation

- Don't run two separate SQL statements. That is more expensive and widens the time frame for race conditions. Use one `UPDATE` with a subquery.
- You don't need PL/pgSQL for the simple task. You still *can* use PL/pgSQL, the `UPDATE` stays the same.
- You need to lock the selected row to defend against race conditions. But you cannot do this with the aggregate function you had because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE):

> The locking clauses cannot be used in contexts where returned rows
> cannot be clearly identified with individual table rows; for example
> they **cannot be used with aggregation**.

- Bold emphasis mine. Luckily, you can replace `min(id)` easily with the equivalent `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT 1` like demonstrated above. Can use an index just as well.
- If the table is big, you need an index on `id` for performance. Assuming that `id` is already indexed as `PRIMARY KEY`. But this additional [partial, multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) will help *a lot more*:

  ```
    CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON table (id_type, id)
    WHERE id_used IS NULL;
  ```

### Alternative solutions

**Advisory locks** or `SKIP LOCKED` may be superior:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

Or you may want to lock **many rows at once**:

- [How to mark certain nr of rows in table on concurrent access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27446515/how-to-mark-certain-nr-of-rows-in-table-on-concurrent-access/27454675#27454675)

Comment: @King: You may also be interested in the link I added. Also, if that answers your question, consider accepting the answer.