# PostgreSQL generic handler for serialization failure

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

This is a followup question from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366621/postgresql-transaction-restart) so I know I can use (blocking) LOCKs but I want to use predicate locks and serializable transaction isolation.

What I'd like to have is a generic handler of serialization failures that would retry the function/query X number of times.

As example, I have this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE account_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE account
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('account_id_seq'),
  title character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  balance integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT account_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO account (title) VALUES ('Test Account');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytest() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    cc integer;
BEGIN
    cc := balance from account where id=1;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Balance: %', cc;
    perform pg_sleep(3);

    update account set balance = cc+10 where id=1 RETURNING balance INTO cc;

    return cc;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myretest() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    tries integer := 5;
BEGIN
    WHILE TRUE LOOP
        BEGIN -- nested block for exception
            RETURN mytest();
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN SQLSTATE '40001' THEN
                IF tries > 0 THEN
                    tries := tries - 1;
                    RAISE NOTICE 'Restart! % left', tries;
                ELSE
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'NO RESTARTS LEFT';
                END IF;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So if call `mytest()` directly concurrently I get a serialization failure on the last commit:

```
4SO$ psql -c "select mytest()" & PIDA=$! && psql -c "select mytest()" && wait $PIDA
[1] 4909
NOTICE:  Balance: 0
NOTICE:  Balance: 0
 mytest 
--------
     10
(1 row)

ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "update account set balance = cc+10 where id=1 RETURNING balance"
PL/pgSQL function mytest() line 10 at SQL statement
```

If I call `myretest()` it should try to execute `mytest()` up until the 5th try where it would raise the exception.

So I have two points here (where maybe point 2 also invalidates point 1):

- `myretest()` does not work as expected, every iteration results in serialiation_failure exception even after the concurrent thread finishes: is there something I should add to "reset" the transaction?
- how could I make this (`myretest()` logic) generic so that it would apply to every called function in the system without the need for "wrapper" functions as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializable transactions provide exactly what you are looking for as long as you use some framework that starts the transaction over when it receives an error with a `SQLSTATE` of `40001` or `40P01`.

In PostgreSQL a function always runs in the context of a transaction.  You can't start a new transaction within the context of a "wrapper" function.  That would require a slightly different feature, which is commonly called a "stored procedure" -- something which doesn't exist in PostgreSQL.  Therefore, you need to put the logic to manage the restart into code which submits the transaction to the database.  Fortunately, there are many connectors for that -- Java, perl, python, tcl, ODBC, etc.  There is even a connector for making a separate connection to a PostgreSQL database within a PostgreSQL procedural language, which might allow you to do something like what you want:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

I have seen this done in various "client" frameworks.  Clearly it is a bad idea to spread this around to all locations where the application is logically dealing with the database, but there are many good reasons to route all database requests through one "accessor" method (or at least a very small number of them), and most frameworks provide a way to deal with this at that layer. (For example, in Spring you would want to create a transaction manager using dependency injection.) That probably belongs in some language you are using for your application logic, but if you really wanted to you could probably use plpgsql and dblink; that's probably not going to be your easiest path, though.